# Using the console to alter object variables

Tags: c#, input, xna, console

I am unsure of the actual terms for any of this, for which I am sure there are I just happen to not be aware of them.

The application is simply an XNA game. I want to be able to alter variables without recompiling,  with the use of a console (currently just using the C# console) as that allows me more control than using key presses to increment and decrement.

I assume I will have to have a thread constantly waiting for input from the console but what I am unsure of is how to go about altering variables within an object (such as velocity, acceleration, gravity etc).

Is there a quick way of doing this without a huge case statement? If anyone knows the actual names of any techniques / what I am actually looking for that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit:** there seems to be some confusion as to what I am actually looking for. I do not need an in-game console as I have added a regular console using AllocConsole(). My main question was regarding how to call specific objects using this console and change their variables while the application is still running.

**Edit2:** after some research online with the queries "command console" and "developer console" I have managed to find [this](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Console_Variables_And_Commands.shtml) page on CVars and [this](http://www.randygaul.net/2013/01/04/c-reflection-part-4-variant/) page on variants. I feel like both of these are a step towards what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you be more specific? All that almost every computer program ever written does is take input from a human and change the contents of variables accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can be more specific. I need to be able to reference an object within the game and alter a value. Something like typing "player1.velocity = 20.0f" and having the players velocity, in the game, change to 20.0f. I am simply not sure what the best way to go about it is. My main goal is to avoid recompiling every time I want to change some values.

Comment: I think I see. You want an in-game console for testing or debugging purposes, like the one you get if you press tilde (`~`) in Quake. Some casual Googling turned up [someone's attempt](http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2010/08/developer-console-plugin-for-xna-games.html). If you're OK with some compromises in elegance and a Turing-incomplete input language, something like that might do.

Comment: I was planning on using the C# console and just reading the input but this is actually much more ideal. This does look like it has the functionality I need, I'll give it a shot. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. :) It's totally OK to write and accept your own answer by the way -- I don't know how I should phrase it and you know best what worked.

Comment: Thanks, but the entire question isn't answered yet. I'd like to know how to reference the objects and their variables properly. I'll probably just look through the console code you linked and see how they did it. Maybe someone else can come along and answer that part of the question though. The code you linked was for XNA 3.0 though, [I found some for 4.0 online though](https://code.google.com/r/jameswalkoski-xnagameconsole-xna4/source/browse). Someone was nice enough to convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the second edit in the first post you'll see where my research took me.

The CVar link looks the most promising but it was 14 years ago. It is still the best answer but I feel there is probably a more modern / better approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Writing an in-game console system is not something that is very simple to do. What I would recommend you start off with doing is to use an XML or JSON file for configuration, and have it dynamically load in the values. That way you don't need to recompile every time you change a variable, and you don't need to go through the hassle of setting up an in-game console/command window.

Comment: The system does not need to be in-game. I just want a quick way of altering variables while I am inside an XNA window. I believe you can still listen to the C# console, like you would in a console app. My idea was to use that to listen for inputs. My question was mainly about the best way to handle the inputs.